# Por quê não estou conseguindo fazer o INSERT no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

```
<?php

class Connection
{
    private $nome;
    private $data_nascimento;
    private $genero;
    private $rg;
    private $cpf;
    private $email;
    private $telefone_fixo;
    private $telefone_celular;
    private $cidade;
    private $estado;
    private $rua;
    private $cep;
    private $entrada;
    private $saida;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->nome = strip_tags($_POST['nome']);
        $this->data_nascimento = $_POST['data_nascimento'];
        $this->genero = strip_tags($_POST['data_nascimento']);
        $this->rg = strip_tags($_POST['rg']);
        $this->cpf = strip_tags($_POST['cpf']);
        $this->email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
        $this->telefone_fixo = strip_tags($_POST['telefone_fixo']);
        $this->telefone_celular = strip_tags($_POST['telefone_celular']);
        $this->cidade = strip_tags($_POST['cidade']);
        $this->estado = strip_tags($_POST['estado']);
        $this->rua = strip_tags($_POST['rua']);
        $this->cep = strip_tags($_POST['cep']);
        $this->entrada = strip_tags($_POST['entrada']);
        $this->saida = strip_tags($_POST['saida']);
    }

    public function conexao()
    {
        echo "Hello World!";
        try {
            // criando a conexao com o banco de dados
            $connect = new PDO(
                "mysql:localhost;dbname=nomedobancodedados", // host & database name
                "nomedousuario", // database username
                "senhadobancodedados" // database password
            );
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        $insert = $connect->prepare('INSERT INTO wp_check_in (nome, data_nascimento, genero, rg, cpf, email, telefone_fixo, telefone_celular, cidade, estado, rua, cep, entrada, saida) VALUES(:nome, :data_nascimento, :genero, :rg, :cpf, :email, :telefone_fixo, :telefone_celular, :cidade, :estado, :rua, :cep, :entrada, :saida)');
        $insert->execute(array(
            ':nome' => $this->nome,
            ':data_nascimento' => $this->data_nascimento,
            ':genero' => $this->genero,
            ':rg' => $this->rg,
            ':cpf' => $this->cpf,
            ':email' => $this->email,
            ':telefone_fixo' => $this->telefone_fixo,
            ':telefone_celular' => $this->telefone_celular,
            ':cidade' => $this->cidade,
            ':estado' => $this->estado,
            ':rua' => $this->rua,
            ':cep' => $this->cep,
            ':entrada' => $this->entrada,
            ':saida' => $this->saida,
        ));
    }
}

$connect = new Connection();

// validando o envio dos dados da parte do check-in
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $connect->conexao();
}

?>
```

Gostaria de entender o que esta acontecendo? Por quê não consigo realizar o INSERT desses campos no Banco?

Grato,
João Paulo.

Comment: `mysql:localhost;dbname=nomedobancodedados` não seria `mysql:dbname=nomedobancodedados;host=localhost`?

Comment: Lembre de colocar a mensagem de erro, parece que você o `host=` na string de conexão.

Comment: @rray Parece que você esqueceu o "esqueceu" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique a sua conexão com o banco de dados

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meuBancoDeDados', $username, $password);
```

Comment: Cara valeu mesmo, ajudou bastante realmente verifiquei a conexão e percebi que não havia colocado o :host= após o mysql. Funcionou direitinho, valeu... Forte abraço e tenha um ótimo dia.